# How resolve error:Conflicting type for "snprintf"

Tags: compiler-errors, osx-lion, xcode4.5, llvm-gcc, llvm-clang

In my app i used **Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C** is **Apple LLVM compiler 4.1** for simulator.
For simulator this is working. When i compiling same code for Device i changed **Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C** is **LLVM GCC 4.2.** This time i am getting error in stdio.h "Conflicting types for"sprintf" ".

I am using Mac OS x 10.7.4
Xcode 4.5(iOS 6)

This is working fine in (Mac OS x 10.7.4 & Xcode 4.2.3(iOS 5)) && (Mac OS x 10.6.8 & Xcode 3.2.3(iOS 4)).

What is the difference between iOS 5 and iOS 6 for LLVM Compiler. any one please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this warning when compiling a Universal App under Mac OS X, when using data types `NSInteger` or `NSUInteger`:

```
NSInteger thing = 7;
NSLog(@"Thing is %ld", thing);
```

This will work under 64-bit, but give warnings under 32-bit (hint; iOS uses 32-bit architecture).

The (ugly) solution is to force `thing` to `long` in this case:

```
NSLog(@"Thing is %ld", (long)thing);
```

Which will work everywhere.

This is better than:

```
#ifdef __x86_64
NSLog(@"Thing is %ld", thing);
#else
NSLog(@"Thing is %d", thing);
#endif
```

Comment: Hi trojanfoe, i am using string in so many places. It's difficult to modify all places. Any other solution is there or can we convert 64 bit to 32 bit.

Comment: @sreenivas No; it's worth the effort fixing the code regardless of how long it will take.  If you don't then you will become accustomed to warnings when compiling and miss an important one that will bite you in the bum.

Comment: What about string? How can i use string.

Comment: @sreenivas What do you mean?  What string warnings are being generated?